# No implicit converson from nil to String

Tags: ruby

I am getting an error

```
ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:36:in `open': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
```

here `@filename`, `@directory` and `@xmlFile` all have `String` as class type if I print them.
But somehow still in `eval_script` the above error is thrown. I don't undertstand why?

```
def execute
  ...
  @result = eval_script(@filename,@xmlFile,@directory)
end

def eval_script filename,xml,directory
  proc = Proc.new{}
  eval(File.read(filename),proc.binding, filename)
end
```

Edit:
1) execute method is my rails action controller method.

Script:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc =  Nokogiri::XML(open(ARGV.first))
path = ARGV[1]
print path
File.delete(path + "/testOut.txt") if File.exist?(path + "/testOut.txt")
file = File.open(path + "/testOut.txt", 'w')
doc.css('testcases').each { |node| file.write "#{node['name']}\n" if node.css('results[test="testOut"]').any? }
```

Comment: I think the error might be in the file `filename` you are trying to evaluate. Can you verify that `filename` runs fine?. Also you aren't using the argument `xml` in the method `eval_script`.

Comment: @Rashmirathi: Filename with path is correct. I can open that file by putting in Run Window(I am using Windows) 2)It takes the input by proc.binding so I think it doesn't need to mention the arguments.

Comment: The problem is most likely in the script you're trying to evaluate, not in the code you've posted in your message.
Can you show us the content of the file referenced by @filename

Comment: Also, please post the FULL trace of the error.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn: Added the script, If I directly run this script it works fine.

Comment: How do I share the FULL trace , it is lengthy(because of rails)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there's your problem.  Line 4 of your script is

```
doc =  Nokogiri::XML(open(ARGV.first))
```

But there are no ARGV elements being passed, so you're trying to open `nil`

Since you have the binding available, just refer to the variables defined in the `eval_script` method.

```
doc =  Nokogiri::XML(open(xml))
```